# How to transfer my Firebase Realtime database to Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm already using Firebase Realtime database, but now Firebase has launched Cloud Firestore for database so, how can I transfer my data from realtime database to firestore as I already have users and they are using realtime database on the android app.

So, is there a way that I can transfer the database to firestore?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639693/converting-firebase-database-to-cloud-firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a magic button that can convert your database from the `Realtime Database` to `Cloud Firestore`, there isn't one! And as far as I read, Firebase creators won't create one. So unfortunately, you'll need to convert the database yourself.

Comment: yaa, I figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has published a [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb) for migrating from Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore.

**Edit:** It seems they have changed that page. [Here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FUx_Xh8Uc7AJ:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) is a cached version of their migration guide published earlier.

Comment: I see no mention of migration, only a comparison?

Comment: @Whitebird Looks like they've changed that page. I've edited my answer with a cached version of their previous migration guide.

Comment: On that page they have only told that you can do this, but not exactly shown how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you changing now, its is still in its BETA version and they are coming up with new things every now and then. I suggest to wait.
Let them make up their mind first :P

Comment: yaa, and there is not even a proper way to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

i made a script for converting data from firebase to firestore

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
constructor(
private afs: AngularFirestore,
private angularfire: AngularFireDatabase
) { }convert() {
this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('requests'); //ref()
this.angularfire.list('/requests/').auditTrail().subscribe((data: any) => {
  _.each(data, element => {
    this.itemsCollection.doc(element.key).set(element.payload.val())
      .then((result) => {
      });
  });
});}
```